# C++ Curl Multi Perform Blocking Issue

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

In my QT app, I been using curl's `curl_easy_setopt`, and notice that its actually synchronous which was blocking my main gui. Inside my app I have a timer that has a set interval that calls curl. Anytime my timer callback would run curl, it would block my app for a few seconds than continue. So now im trying to figure out how to perform curl's multi interface and multi perform which is asynchronous, and its giving me the same blocking/lagging issue. Can anyone give me advice.

Below is my code, as well as curl's website demo for multi perform.

```
/********Header Files******/
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
....

/************My Timer runs the code below every 10 seconds************/  

std::string url = searchEngineParam.toStdString();
std::string userAgent = options[5]->userAgentsOptions[0].toStdString();

CURL *http_handle;
CURLM *multi_handle;
int still_running; /* keep number of running handles */
int repeats = 0;
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
http_handle = curl_easy_init();

curl_easy_setopt(http_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(http_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(http_handle,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,userAgent.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(http_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_easy_setopt(http_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
curl_easy_setopt(http_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);

 /* init a multi stack */
 multi_handle = curl_multi_init();

 /* add the individual transfers */
 curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, http_handle);

 /* we start some action by calling perform right away */
 curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);

 do {
   CURLMcode mc; /* curl_multi_wait() return code */
   int numfds;

   /* wait for activity, timeout or "nothing" */
   mc = curl_multi_wait(multi_handle, NULL, 0, 1000, &numfds);

   if(mc != CURLM_OK) {
     fprintf(stderr, "curl_multi_wait() failed, code %d.\n", mc);
     break;
   }

   /* 'numfds' being zero means either a timeout or no file descriptors to
      wait for. Try timeout on first occurrence, then assume no file
      descriptors and no file descriptors to wait for means wait for 100
      milliseconds. */

   if(!numfds) {
     repeats++; /* count number of repeated zero numfds */
     if(repeats > 1) {
       WAITMS(100); /* sleep 100 milliseconds */
     }
   }
   else
     repeats = 0;

   curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);
 } while(still_running);

 curl_multi_remove_handle(multi_handle, http_handle);

 curl_easy_cleanup(http_handle);

 curl_multi_cleanup(multi_handle);

 curl_global_cleanup();
```

Comment: How is `qt` tag relevant to this question?

Comment: Its the framework im using

Comment: Ok but the question seems completely irrelevant to Qt. You could have used wxWidgets instead or GTK+ or anything else and it would seemingly change nothing regarding your question. People such as myself use tags to filter the questions they might be able to help with. I strongly doubt Qt knowledge alone can help much here, only perhaps in "drop this entire curl thing and use QtNetwork instead" fashion. UPD: ok, I see Qt tag is no longer here, thanks )